# image link doesn't work on larger screens

Tags: html

I have a website now that includes galleries of images `<img src="">` within link tags.  They work fine on my laptop, but on the 27'' mac, they don't register as links (the cursor doesn't turn from an arrow to a pointer, and you can't click on it).  The site can be found [here](http://emmaferreira.com/tromi), and it's all basic html.

I just can't even being to imagine what I could do to remedy this.

Comment: Please do not link you your site. Read this first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: What browsers are you using on the different machines?

Comment: I am using chrome on my machine and safari on the other.

Comment: the code literally looks like: `<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/tromi/velvet.jpg"><img src="thumbs/tromi/velvetthumb.jpg"></a>` but on the bigger screen it is as if the image isn't mapped for a link at all.  ALSO, even on the laptop, the entire image doesn't link, just the right half of it.